# Cant pull data from spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am creating a Point of Sale in google app script for a web app. I am at the point of pulling data from a google sheet... to load into the web app when I scan the upc code. My goal is to load the info on a form side in a container and then transfer that data to the receipt in a separate container... right now I cannot get the information to load... here is what I have so far...

my spreadsheet looks like....

upc              name  description   price  tax       qty on hand
362032140056    fries   crispy       12.99  0.05    *this will be a calculated field from other sheets

my code....

```
function getItem(scan_item){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Items");
  var data = ws.getRange(1,1,ws.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues();

  var itemsList = data.map(function(r){ return r[0]; });
  var nameList = data.map(function(r){ return r[1]; }); 

  var position = itemsList.indexOf(scan_item);
  if(position > 0){
      return nameList[position];
  } else {
      return "Item Not Found!"

  }


}




document.getElementById("scan-id").addEventListener("input",getItemInfo);


function getItemInfo(){

    var scan_item = document.getElementById("scan-id").value;
    
    if(scan_item.length === 12){
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateItemInfo).getData(scan_item);
    }

}

function updateItemInfo(name){
  document.getElementById("name-id").value = name;
}
```

---

my html....
plain text boxes with disabled txt boxesx for data i want to pull...

```
<section class="item-info form">
        <div class="item-container" id="item-info">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s6">
                    <label for="disabled"class="active">Item:</label>
                    <input disabled value= "": id="name-id" type="text" class="validate">
                    <input disabled value="" id="description-id" type="text" class="validate">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s1">
                    <label for="disabled">Price:</label>
                    <input disabled value="" id="price-id" type="text" class="validate">
                </div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <label for="disabled">QTY:</label>
                    <input disabled value="" id="qty-id" type="text" class="validate">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                 <div class="input-field col s2">
                   <label for="disabled">On Hand:</label>
                   <input disabled value="" id="onHand-id" type="text" class="validate">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <form class="col s12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                        <label for="scan_item">SKU</label>
                        <input placeholder="Scan Item" id="scan-id" type="text" class="validate">
                    </div>
                </div>   
        </div>
    
    </section>
```

as of now if I enter a upc that is in the list I do not get the "item not found!" message...
if I enter a upc that is not in the list the message appears... so I must have something right... I just need the name and other info to pull through.... can anyone help me with this... I would also like to add on enter to move to receipt.. I know I would have to show more code for detailed commands.. but if anyone has a general one they would like to share and about where to put it that would be awesome.

Comment: I think it is only a typo in the question but not in the original script: `.getData(scan_item);` . Regarding your problem, I am not confident but can you try `change` event?

Comment: I removed the tag `r` from your question. Please note: You can hover your mouse over a tag to see a summary of what the tag represents. For `r` you will see "_R is a free, open-source programming language and software environment..._". Tagging a question with irrelevant languages can lead to down-votes - and I am trying to help you avoid that from happening here. If too many of your questions are down-voted, you may end up being unable to ask any questions at all (because you will be question-banned).

Comment: Please also take a look at the overall formatting of your question, as it is a bit of a mess, right now. Note the triple-backticks in the middle of your code block. Those need to appear at the start of a line, with no spaces in front of them. Take a look at the [formatting guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: @idfurw I am not sure what you mean by change event I dont see what's wrong with the .getData(scan_item) please elaborate.. thank you

Comment: @Andrewjames my main question is.. how do I pull product info from a google sheet by scanning a upc code. I will remove the triple back ticks they are not in my original code... they are only on here...

Comment: Your code is `getItem(scan_item)` but your html(js) is `getData(scan_item)`, different function name

Comment: You can also remove those `<pre>` and `</pre>` tags from the code in your question (I am sure they do not exist in the code you are actually executing). The code you show us should match the code you are using.

Comment: ahhh okay yes... bc i have this function too..... i probably need to remove it altogether... here is the other funcion

Comment: function getData() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let ws = ss.getSheetByName("Items");
  let res = {};
  res.items = ws.getRange(2 , 1, ws.getLastRow()-1, 5).getValues();
  ws = ss.getSheetByName("Sales");
  res.sales = ws.getRange(2, 1, ws.getLastRow()-1, 6).getValues();
  return res;